# Trigger JS Event on window.onload and pick the processed html parameters directly from the input field

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to Trigger an event on pageload, however I want the event to use the parameters that are already outputted by the Php/Server into html on the input field.

This is an example input field with the parameters dynamics outputted by php

```
<input type = "text" id = "abc" onload = "test_function('parameter_1','parameter_2','parameter_3');">
```

Sample function

```
test_function('parameter_1','parameter_2','parameter_3'){
alert("Hello World");
}
```

I am using the below window.onload event to call the function post page load, but I do not want to give the parameters here instead pick it up from the html in input field

```
window.onload = test_function();
```

is it possible ?

Can i do it with addeventlistener, would it pick up the parameters from the input field - html

Comment: You can't populate/read your inputs until your DOM is loaded.. so use something like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func, false);`

Comment: If you want to populate your input with values coming from your server, you might want to use the `value` attribute: `<input type="text" id="abc" value="<? your_value; ?>">`

Comment: `window.onload = test_function();` needs to be `window.onload = test_function;` However, to use stuff echoed by PHP, you need an anonymous function: `window.onload = function() { test_function(<?= $param1 ?>); };` Best try and ask about your problem, not about the solution you think is the correct one. Your approach is flawed.

Comment: @Chris G , I am creating charts in JS. Plan is to populate data in PHP, print first as  html and then sent the numbers calcuated from the Php data to the chart function in JS through Ajax and then print the chart -- all should happen in 1 go

Comment: So why not: 1. serve base HTML 2. load chart data via AJAX 3. display charts?

Comment: @Chris G , 1. server base HTML 2. how do i give chart data to AJAX midst and after php processing the data ?

Comment: 1. make AJAX request to server 2. PHP script processes data, sends back JSON containing data 3. AJAX success method now has data (not to be rude, but your questions suggest you don't really understand how AJAX works. It's essentially a way to communicate with the server without leaving the current page; it allows you to both send data to the server and receive a reply, what else do you need?)

Comment: @Chris G ,anonymous function did the Job, thanks Chris